# Android- Float the image continiously over the screen

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I want to move the two images continuously over the screen. It should float like a bubble in the screen. I have tried something using translate animation and alpha animation but that is not working it is floating the image for few seconds only but i want to move/float images continuously on complete screen area.  How to do that? If any one have the idea please let me know, Here is my code, please check it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l);
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(1000);
// animation.setRepeatCount(10);
set.addAnimation(animation);
animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,  0.0f, 
                                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,  0.0f, 
                                   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 10.0f);
animation.setDuration(1500);
set.addAnimation(animation);

LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);
l.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
controller.start();
```

Comment: image? what image? there is no image here

Comment: Here layout is animating, in tha layout image is there. it s in xml @psklink

Comment: use a `TimeAnimator` in a custom View that draws your `Bitmap`, layout animations are designed for something else